# Neukirch Algebraic NT 12.12

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I do not understand Theorem (12.12) at page 81 in Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory.
I can verify each line of the proof, but the following is so clear?

{\bf Problem}
Let $o$ be an order in an algebraic number field $K$.
Let $f$ be the conductor of $o$, i.e. the biggest ideal of the integral closure $\tilde{o}$ which is contained in $o$.
Then, is the number of the units $(o/f)^*$ finite?

Comment: Is the ring $o/f$ finite?

Comment: I don't know it. Do I miss something trivial?

Comment: Trivial is in the eye of the beholder. Are you aware that all nonzero ideals in the integers of a number field have finite index? If not, you should figure that out, and then the argument should carry over to orders as well. Finiteness of these quotient rings is fundamental: it is part of what makes number theory separate from commutative algebra. You couldn't define the zeta-function of a number field without knowing that all nonzero ideals in the ring of integers have finite index (look up the definition of the norm of an ideal).

Comment: Thank you very much. By 2.12, $o_K/f$ is finite. The smaller $o/f$ is also finite. I understood.